# Changing the value while two pointers pointing to the same location

Tags: c, pointers

I tried to figure out the behavior of two pointers pointing the same address. And to try it myself I wrote the code below. This one confused me. What is the difference here ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *ptr = "hey!";
    char *copyPtr = ptr;

    printf("%p\n", ptr);
    printf("%p\n", copyPtr);

    printf("%s\n", ptr);
    printf("%s\n", copyPtr);

    copyPtr = "changed!";

    printf("%p\n", ptr);
    printf("%p\n", copyPtr);

    printf("%s\n", ptr);
    printf("%s\n", copyPtr);

    printf("\n\n");

    int *ptr1 = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *ptr1 = 1;
    int *copyPtr1 = ptr1;

    printf("%p\n", ptr1);
    printf("%p\n", copyPtr1);

    printf("%d\n", *ptr1);
    printf("%d\n", *copyPtr1);

    *copyPtr1 = 2;

    printf("%p\n", ptr1);
    printf("%p\n", copyPtr1);

    printf("%d\n", *ptr1);
    printf("%d\n", *copyPtr1);

    free(ptr1);
}
```

Here is the output. I was waiting the output to be like "changed!" and "changed!". `ptr` and `copyPtr` should be pointing to the same address right ? When I change the value inside this address they should both change and the address should remain same. Why is that not the case ?

On the other hand when it is done with dynamic memory allocation there seems like no problem.

```
0x4007e4
0x4007e4
hey!
hey!
0x4007e4
0x4007ed
hey!
changed!


0xa9f420
0xa9f420
1
1
0xa9f420
0xa9f420
2
2
```

The answers to similar questions didn't really satisfy me, or this may be a duplicate question, I am therefore sorry in that case..

Comment: What specifically about this do you find confusing?

Comment: `copyPtr1 = ptr1;` - just leaked the memory allocated on the prior line, and reset the `copyPtr1` variable to point to the same memory as `ptr1`. Does *that* clear it up?

Comment: Why in the first case when I changed the value only the second one changed ? In the second case I changed one and both of them changed though ?

Comment: This is just a dump of multiple statements of code and a general "I don't get it" please *edit your question* to indicate what you don't get and why, with specifics about what you expect to be the case in those situations.

Comment: At the first change, it changed because you reassigned the pointer with `copyPtr = "changed!";`. Aside: start with the correct syntax for printing a pointer such as `printf("%p\n", (void*)ptr);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, you change the *value* of `copyPtr` to the address of a string constant.  This string constant lives at a different address from the first one.  So after this change, the pointer values are different, as are what they point to.

In the second case you're not actually changing `copyPtr1`.  You're dereferencing it and changing the value *it points to*, which is the same value that `ptr1` points to.  So the change in value is reflected when you dereference `ptr1`.  The fact that you used `malloc` in this case is irrelevant.  What is relevant is that you dereferenced the pointer in this case, while in the former you did not.

In order for the first case to show a change in `ptr`,  you would need to dereference `copyPtr` instead of changing its value.  Note however that string constants are just that -- constant.  You can't change them, and attempting to do so will likely cause a segmentation fault.  If on the other hand the memory pointed to is created dynamically, then you can change it.

For example, this is invalid:

```
char *ptr = "hey!";
char *copyPtr = ptr;
strcpy(copyPtr, "hi!");    // invalid: attempt to write to a string constant
```

But this will work:

```
char *ptr = strdup("hey!");
char *copyPtr = ptr;
strcpy(copyPtr, "hi!");    // OK, but be careful not to overrun the buffer
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between the first change - `copyPtr = "changed!";` and the second change - `*copyPtr1 = 2;`

While the 1st one changes address of copyPtr to point to a const section (.ro section) in the object file while the 2nd one keeps the pointer copyPtr1 pointed to the same memory in heap just modifies it's contents.. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The code:

```
copyPtr = "changed!";
```

changes the pointer to point to the new string literal as shown in the output:

```
0x4007e4
0x4007ed
hey!
changed!
```

If you want to change the value at the original address, use strcpy().

In the second one where you malloc memory, you are dereferencing the pointer so the value changed as expected (rather than the pointer).

Answer (score 0):

in this statement

```
copyPtr = "changed!";
```

there is changed the value stored in the pointer `copyPtr` itself.

Now the pointer points to the first character of the string literal `"changed!"`.

In this statement

```
*ptr1 = 1;
```

there is changed the object pointed to by the pointer `ptr1` because in the statement the pointer is dereferenced. The value of the pointer itself was not changed. It still keeps the address of the allocated memory in the statement

```
int *ptr1 = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

You could achieve the same result with the previous pointers. For example

```
char s[] = "hey!";
char *ptr = s;
char *copyPtr = ptr;

// ...

*copyPtr = 'H';

puts( ptr );
puts( copyPtr );
```

Thus in the code snippets above there are changed different values. In the first example there is changed the value of the pointer itself.

And in the second example there is changed the value of the object pointed to by the pointer. The value of the pointer itself was not changed. As result the both pointers still point to the same one object that was changed.